# How to upload more than 1 image in fileimagearbehavior extension for Yii

Tags: php, image-processing, yii, yii-extensions

I try to use fileimagearbehavior extension for Yii, and its not a lot documentation for that. In examples I just found how can 1 file be uploaded, but I cant find way how to upload more than 1 file. Here example

```
class Dish extends CActiveRecord {
    public $recipeImg; // used by the form to send the file.

    public function rules()
        {
        return array(
                // ...
                // for the form too
                array('recipeImg', 'file', 'types' => 'png, gif, jpg', 'allowEmpty' => true),
               // ...
            );
        }

      public function behaviors() {
            return array(
               'recipeImgBehavior' => array(
                   'class' => 'ImageARBehavior',
                    'attribute' => 'recipeImg', // this must exist
                    'extension' => 'png, gif, jpg', // possible extensions, comma separated
                    'prefix' => 'img_',
                    'relativeWebRootFolder' => 'files/recipes', // this folder must exist

                    # 'forceExt' => png, // this is the default, every saved image will be a png one.
                    # Set to null if you want to keep the original format

                    'useImageMagick' => '/usr/bin', # I want to use imagemagick instead of GD, and
                    # it is located in /usr/bin on my computer.

                        // this will define formats for the image.
                    // The format 'normal' always exist. This is the default format, by default no
                    // suffix or no processing is enabled.
                    'formats' => array(
                        // create a thumbnail grayscale format
                        'thumb' => array(
                            'suffix' => '_thumb',
                            'process' => array('resize' => array(60, 60), 'grayscale' => true),
                        ),
                               // create a large one (in fact, no resize is applied)
                        'large' => array(
                             'suffix' => '_large',
                        ),
                        // and override the default :
                        'normal' => array(
                           'process' => array('resize' => array(200, 200)),
                         ),
                     ),
                    'defaultName' => 'default', // when no file is associated, this one is used by getFileUrl
                   // defaultName need to exist in the relativeWebRootFolder path, and prefixed by prefix,
                   // and with one of the possible extensions. if multiple formats are used, a default file must exist
                   // for each format. Name is constructed like this :
                   //     {prefix}{name of the default file}{suffix}{one of the extension}
                )
           );
     }
}
```

And here piece of view:
     `echo $form->fileField($model,'recipe');`

Comment: BY saing 'upload multiple file' You mean that ONE form.field ("recipeImg") should be able to upload more than one file? OR You have another fomr.field ("recipeImg_second") and want to upload file from second field?

Comment: Preferably, this is - when you fill one file field another file field appear. Or like you said one file field should be able to upload more than one file. Nubmer of files should not be fixed

Comment: I never have to do it, but this article seems to be well explained :) http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/47613-uploading-file/page__p__223243#entry223243.

Comment: Let me know if it works. Maybe in the future I'll need :)

Comment: Thanks, its works, but need a lot of corrections for you needs